# How do you access appsetting.json parameters in an AuthorizeAttribute class in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, appsettings, authorize-attribute, iauthorizationfilter

In my ASP.NET Core MVC app, I have a class that inherits from AuthorizeAttribute and implements IAuthorizationFilter.

```
namespace MyProject.Attributes
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public class AllowGroupsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly List<PermissionGroups> groupList = null;
        public AllowGroupsAttribute(params PermissionGroups[] groups)
        {
            groupList = groups.ToList();
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var executingUser = context.HttpContext.User;

            //If the user is not authenticated then prevent execution
            if (!executingUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.Result = new StatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to decorate a controller method with something like `[AllowGroups(PermissionGroups.Admin, PermissionGroups.Level1]`

What I plan to do, is retreive group names from appsettings.json  based on the enum values listed and check that the user is a member of those groups.

My question is, what is the correct way to access the app settings from within my attribute class?

Comment: configure settings on startup either via options or concrete object model and then resolve them through the `HttpContext.RequestServices`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Configure settings on startup,

Either via options

```
services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("groups"));
```

Or concrete object model

```
MySettings settings = Configuration.GetSection("groups").Get<MySettings>();
services.AddSingleton(settings);
```

And then resolve them through the `HttpContext.RequestServices` within the filter

```
//...

IServiceProvider services = context.HttpContext.RequestServices;

MySettings settings = services.GetService<MySettings>();
//-- OR --
//MySettings settings = services.GetService<IOptions<MySettings>>().Value;

//...
```

while a more service locator approach, it should allow for access to the desired  configuration.

Comment: Thank you.  I think I am a bit closer to getting this implemented now, I have implemented a class with a dictionary to pull the section from settings, no errors there.  But I have a build error on the line `var settings = services.GetService<MySettings>();`.

The error reads _CS0308 The non-generic method 'IServiceProvider.GetService(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments_

Comment: @GarethPN `GetSrvice<T>` is an extension method. You are most likely missing a `using` name space for dependency injection.

Comment: Ah ha! I added `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` to get access to the generic method which resolved my error.  Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and so you solve it

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class AllowGroupsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
            var user = configuration.GetSection("AppConfig").GetSection("user").Value;
            var pass = configuration.GetSection("AppConfig").GetSection("pass").Value;

..........

}
```

in appsettings.json

```
"AppConfig": {
    "user": "hola",
    "pass": "mundo"
  },
```